# Interface to exchange with jms

Tags: java, interface, jms

I'd like to exchange messages with a customer over a jms queue. Something like:

> User updated Address; Field Street; OldValue: foo; NewValue: bar;

What is the best interface to Exchange with the customer? I Could define it like the text above and send as TextMessage. But this is not really an interface I would prefer.

Shall I exchange an API with the java classes? Or use Soap over JMS?
What's the best way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send text or a java objects (that must implement java.io.Serializable interface). If you will use simple text try to make it structured in a structred format xml or Json.

Otherwise use java object transmission

You can send text or a java objects (that must implement java.io.Serializable interface). If you will use simple text try to make it structured in a structred format xml or Json.

If you want to use java objects this may work also. Here is a very simple example :

```
/*the object you will be sent to consumer*/
  public class MSObject implements java.io.Serializable{
  ......
  }

  /*sending method*/
  private void sendObjectMessage() throws Exception {
        ActiveMQSession mysession = (ActiveMQSession) session;
        ObjectMessage msg = session.createObjectMessage();
        msg.setObject( new MSObject("first name","Jimmy") );
        msg.setJMSType(this.CMD_TYPE_MESSAGETYPE_OBJECT);
        producer.send(msg);
        if (transacted) {
            session.commit();
        }
        System.out.println("The object message has been sent to " + this.subject
                + " queue.");
        Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
    }
    /*receiving method*/
    public void onMessage(Message message) {

        if (message instanceof ObjectMessage) {
        System.out.println("recevied a Object Message");
        ObjectMessage msg = (ObjectMessage)message;
        MSObject obj = (MSObject)msg.getObject();
        System.out.println("info: ");
        System.out.println("key: "+obj.getKey());
        System.out.println("value: "+obj.getValue());
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sending Objects sound good, but then I've to exchange/define them with the customer(s). I think I go with the json solution. Even then the interface has to be specified (of course) but it's maybe the most flexible interface. It will be possible to add new fields and not all customers have the care about the. So versioning is also not a big issue.

Comment: Ok sounds good but it you ask me I would go for the object approach.
This way you will avoid generating Json from one side and parsing it from the other side. With the object approach all what you need to do is sharing one jar file containing the interface declaration. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Soap sound like the simplest, any xml wrapping would work.
I would go for google protobufs instead though, then you could send binary data.

Comment: You can send text or a java objects (that must implement java.io.Serializable interface). If you will use simple text try to make it structured in a structred format xml or Json.